# Read Barcode with NFC

Tags: android, nfc, barcode, zxing

I want to **read barcode** using NFC enabled device in android.
how to achieve this?
The one option is **read barcode** using camera.
But read it using NFC.
This [Library](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) provides reading barcode using camera.
But I want read barcode using NFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [Android documentation about NFC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)? There is descriped how to read that tags.

Comment: yup.. i read it so i m not using that...
I m using this link to read Mi-fare card
[link] (https://github.com/nadam/nfc-reader)

Comment: any idea how can i do it??

Comment: Can we read barcode using ant Library as it is prompting user to install app.. And i dnt want that.

Comment: About the NFC stuff I just read that basics. About ZXing you can simple embedd that app in your own. I'm pretty sure that there are some tutorials how to make that. I did that already myself.